# Powering Arduino from 12 V

Tags: power-supply, arduino-uno

I’m making an automatic dog feeder with an Arduino Uno as the brains and a stepper motor (taking 12 V, hence the need for the 12 V power supply) as the muscles. I want to power the whole unit from a single 12 V power supply to keep things simple going out of the electronics case.

I’m pretty sure an Arduino can take 12 V directly but I’ve heard it can overheat the power regulator and, as this will be outside and on for long periods of time, I don’t want to risk having any problems.

As a novice at electronics, the only solution I’ve come up with is to use a buck converter to step down the 12 V to the 5 V an Arduino would handle much better. Is this viable or are there other, better options?

Comment: Are you using 12 volt solenoids?

Comment: I forgot to add, I’m powering a stepper motor that need 12V to move a screw that dispenses the food. I was hoping to take power from that, step it down, and power the arduino. If it comes down to it, I can just use an additional plug to power the arduino but I was hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: Please add any extra info to the question and not in the comments.

Comment: A buck converter makes sense. Else get a heatsink for your linear regulator.

Comment: Some of the larger arduino come with a 5v regulator that can take 12V. Easy way to tell is they have a barrel jack.  You can always add another regulator yourself and feed the usb port; just don't forget to also use appropriate capacitors to keep the regulators happy if they do not come built in as a package.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into getting that put together.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino can run fine from 12 V so long as it's not powering lots of extra stuff off its 5 V output pins.

It sounds like you have a stepper motor driver chip, but the motor itself is powered from 12 V, so that's probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look up the current draw of the Arduino MCU and interface chip, add any stuff outside the chips that is on the board (eg. LEDs) and off the board (the rest of your circuit) that is drawing from the on-board 5V regulator, then compare that with the regulator thermal specifications. That's a bit of work and possibly error-prone if you've not done it before.

You can just try it, and if the regulator (often an AMS1117 or similar) is getting too hot to hold your finger on for several seconds (~60°C), then add a buck regulator module or LM78M05 and a capacitor or two. I would guess it's probably okay as-is, but a bit depends on your stepper driver and if it is directly driving optos or whatever, and on the design choices made on the Arduino board itself.